# Generalized Method of Moments Estimation in Python

Tags: statsmodels

I'm am trying to perform Instrumental Variable (IV) regression in Python. I saw online that the statsmodels.gmm package has the function I need (http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/gmm.html#), but when I ran `import statsmodels.gmm as gmm` in Python I get this error `No module named gmm`
. I'm using ipython with python 2.7.9. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you download the package and add it to your local python installation?

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned below the gmm models are still in the sandbox and therefore are not downloaded with the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMM and related IV estimators are still in the sandbox and have not been included in the statsmodels API yet.

The import needs to be directly from the module

```
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression import gmm
```

Then, these classes can be accessed with, for example `gmm.GMM`

The main models that are currently available are:

`GMM`, `IV2SLS`, `IVGMM`, `LinearIVGMM`, `NonlinearIVGMM`

The mailing list has a recent discussion on the current status, and links to "secret" Gists
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pystatsmodels/o6NY7qGrPw0/vzf897jy3vMJ

(I just found that the `t_test` doesn't work for a `GMM` model.)

Comment: I thought that that might be the issue. Thanks for the help!